# How to use Mupdf sample project with android SDK

Tags: android, mupdf

I  have a pdf reader proejct with mupdf reader library and i have a Android setup SDK , when i run the sample application it display sd card content list and when i have selected any pdf i will get crashed here is the log .

```
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.openFile:(Ljava/lang/String;)J
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.openFile(Native Method)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.<init>(MuPDFCore.java:70)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.openFile(MuPDFActivity.java:216)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:313)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-20 11:57:57.512: E/AndroidRuntime(12750):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please some one tell me how i can run this application

Comment: what you had tried show your code..

Comment: i have found from git hub

Comment: You need to build the library. have you build that..??

Comment: i dont know how it is build please tell me the project not showing any error so i have directly run

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample project to read PDF with file manger.

[apv - APV PDF Viewer](https://code.google.com/p/apv/)

This app using MuPDF to show the PDF file as well using other libraries also to show images and maintain heapsize for that application.

[Steps](https://code.google.com/p/apv/wiki/Building) to bulid the library.

Following are the other similar projects to show PDf file which are as follows :

1. [DroidReade](http://droidreader.googlecode.com/)
2. [VuDroid](http://vudroid.googlecode.com/)